# The executed string value does not match to the hard coded value

Tags: java, matcher, date

In my helper class i'm extracting a key string from a log file. In there im searching for a date and substring that text. The issue is when im including that date included phrase using java date and the hard coded ones are acting in different ways.

The code snippet :

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/developer.log"));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = br.readLine();

        while (line != null) {
            sb.append(line);
            line = br.readLine();
        }

      String second = sb.toString();
      String pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd";
      SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
      String date = "]"+simpleDateFormat.format(new Date());
      Matcher m2 = Pattern.compile("^(.*)date(.*)$").matcher(second);
            if (m2.find()) {
                String keyPrefix = "Bearer ";
                key = keyPrefix + m2.group(1);
            }
        }
        br.close();
        return key;
```

The `date` variable does not return a pattern match but when i hard coded the string as `]2019-03-01` it works. What might be the problem here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are not matching against `date` though. You are matching against `second`. Can you give a sample of `developer.log` and the sample output you want from that?

Comment: Yes i'm matching the pattern(which is "]2019-03-01") exists in the String second

Comment: Your pattern is "^(.*)date(.*)$".  Why do you believe that the java compiler magically replaces the characters "date" within your string with the contents of the `date` variable?

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDate` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Please give an example log line where you had expected a match, along with expected result for that line.

Comment: Just use `String date = "]" + LocalDate.now(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toString();`. Your format agrees with the ISO 8601 standard, so in this case you don’t need any explicit formatter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You match against the fixed pattern "date".

To match against the created date string you have to create your matcher as:

```
Matcher m2 = Pattern.compile("^(.*)"+date+"(.*)$").matcher(second);
```